# script not working after converting it from jquery to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have converted following script from jquery based Ajax to Pure javascript-based Ajax but it is not working

here is Jquery based script

```
var cart = {
'add': function(product_id, quantity) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
        dataType: 'json'
    });
  }
}
```

Here is converted Javascript code

```
function addCart(elements, product_id, quantity) {
    // Creating the XMLHttpRequest object
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Instantiating the request object
    request.open("POST", "/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add", true);

    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    // Defining event listener for readystatechange event
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // Check if the request is compete and was successful
        if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            alert("Success");
        }
    };

    var data = 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1);
    // Sending the request to the server
    request.send(data);
}
```

I think there might be a problem in sending data as I am not that much aware of it.

I changed HTML from

```
<button type="button" onclick="cart.add('{{product_id }}', '{{minimum }}');">Add</button>
```

to

```
<button type="button" onclick="addCart(this, '{{product_id }}', '{{minimum }}');">Add</button>
```

Comment: is there a specific reason you use the old XMLHttpRequest method instead of fetch API?

Comment: @GeneSy actually I am unawre of Fetch API

Comment: Also, please give more information than 'it doesn't work'. What errors do you get?

Comment: You should be using `application/json`, instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in console, I didn't get any error, and success message also alerted but only the problem product won't be added to cart

Comment: Well that's because you've not converted the jQuery line `$('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');` to plain JS

Comment: @AlainCruz I made changes according to your suggestion but no use...

Comment: Also, you need to use `JSON.stringify(data)`, in order to convert your request content into a JSON.

Comment: @AlainCruz where do I need to use ``JSON.stringify(data)``

Comment: Change `request.send(data);` to `request.send(JSON.stringify(data));`, still I am looking into your request, I am seeing into your request I think you are actually just sending one attribute (`product_id`) and on the backend you are splitting it. Do you have access to the backend?

Comment: @AlainCruz yes I can access backend. do i share that?

Comment: Just the method that is receiving the call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208257/discussion-between-asimdev-and-alain-cruz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to send a form encoded message in JS, you either need to submit a form or create a `FormData` object. In your case, we will be creating a `FormData`.

```
// Set the needed params.
let formData = new FormData();
const finalQuantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;
formData.append('product_id', product_id);
formData.append('quantity', finalQuantity);
```

Now, I would recommend using the new `fetch API` instead of using `XMLHttpRequest`. So, your request would look something like the following code.

```
fetch('index.php?route=checkout/cart/add', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        }))
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Success.');
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error.message);
        }).finally(function () {
            console.log('Something you wanna execute even if you caught an error or if the request was successful.');
        });
```

It is on my opinion, much easier to understand and it is easier to translate from jQuery, because of the similar structure.

So, doing all the corresponding changes, your method would end up looking like this.

```
function addCart(element, product_id, quantity) {

    // Set the needed params.
    let formData = new FormData();
    const finalQuantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;
    formData.append('product_id', product_id);
    formData.append('quantity', finalQuantity);

    fetch('index.php?route=checkout/cart/add', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        }))
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Success.');
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error.message);
        }).finally(function () {
            console.log('Something you wanna execute even if you caught an error or if the request was successful.');
        });
}
```

If `fetch` is not allowed, because of browser compatibility, we can still use `XMLHttpRequest`. Your code would just need some minor changes.

```
function addCart(elements, product_id, quantity) {

    // Build the form data.
    let formData = new FormData();
    const finalQuantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;
    formData.append('product_id', product_id);
    formData.append('quantity', finalQuantity);    

    // Creating the XMLHttpRequest object
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Instantiating the request object
    request.open("POST", "/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add");

    // Defining event listener for readystatechange event
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // Check if the request is compete and was successful
        if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            alert("Success");
        }
    };

    request.send(formData);
}
```